# Google speech API v1beta1 (syncrecognize and asyncrecognize API call)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-speech-api

I am a Java developer and I have couple of questions related to Google speech API V1Beta1.

#### Question1 (Syncrecognize case):

I tried to upload (through GCS) small size (less than one min running file) audio file to google speech api it is working But the confidence output level is `0.32497215` only. That is my result is not exactly same to my audio input.

How to increase the confidence level output?

#### Question 2 (Asyncrecognize case):

I tried big size audio file (more than one min running file). This case I used the **API call**:

```
https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:asyncrecognize?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

and **Payload**:

```
"{"config":{"encoding":"LINEAR16","sample_rate": 16000},"audio":{"uri":"gs://" + bucketName +"/"+ objectName + ""}}"
```

Here I got the **output json** like

```
{"name": "57...........................95"}.
```

After getting this output I make new API call (Operation interface) with this name value.

```
https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/operations/57.................................95?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I got the output

```
{
 "name": "57....................................95",
 "done": true,
 "response": {
   "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1beta1.AsyncRecognizeResponse"
 }
}
```

How to proceed the work with this value? I need to get audio speech text.

Please help me to fix this issues. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its better to ask one question at a time.

Comment: On the second part, related question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906527/asyncrecognize-result-is-empty

Comment: Please split question into 2. Are you using examples from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples (speech)?

Answer (score 1):

**Ideas to `Question 1`:**

You should give more details in `RecognitionConfig` object, for example specify the `languageCode` and add hints via the [`SpeechContext` object](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1beta1/RecognitionConfig#SpeechContext).

**Answer to `Question 2`:**

Check the `sample rate` of the audio file, you must be sure that is equal to the rate you gave in the request. You can check it e.g. with the following code `soxi audio_file.flac` (`sox` needed for this one).