# Google Speech API returns null on Asyncrecognize

Tags: c#, .net, google-speech-api

I am a little lost and I am really hoping you can help me out.  I am trying to consume the Google Speech API.  My goal is to take an audio file, send it to Speech API and have it return the text.  This is what I have done so far:
•         Created a project on Google
•         Created a service account
•         Registered an environment variable that points to the json file I downloaded from Google.
•         Installed NuGet GoogleSpeechAPI into Visual Studio 2015

I really don’t know where to go from here.  This is what I tried implementing so far: (modified from borrowed code found on codeproject)

```
var service = new CloudSpeechAPIService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Ayaz",
});

//FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\OA\VS_Projects\Speech\good-morning-google.flac");
//MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
//memoryStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
//fileStream.Read(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
//byte[] BA_AudioFile = memoryStream.GetBuffer();

string path = @"C:\OA\VS_Projects\Speech\good-morning-google.flac";
byte[] BA_AudioFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

SyncRecognizeRequest mySyncReq = new SyncRecognizeRequest();

AsyncRecognizeRequest myRequest = new AsyncRecognizeRequest();
RecognitionAudio audio = new RecognitionAudio();
RecognitionConfig rConfig = new RecognitionConfig();
audio.Content = System.Convert.ToBase64String(BA_AudioFile);
rConfig.Encoding = "FLAC";  // LINEAR16   FLAC   MULAW   AMR   AMR_WB 
rConfig.LanguageCode = "us-EN";
rConfig.SampleRate = 44100;
myRequest.Audio = audio;
myRequest.Config = rConfig;

mySyncReq.Audio = audio;
mySyncReq.Config = rConfig;
//service.Speech.Asyncrecognize(myRequest); 
Operation iOp;
//Operation status;
//Syncrecognize   Asyncrecognize
iOp = service.Speech.Asyncrecognize(myRequest).Execute();

while(true)
{
    if (iOp.Done == true)
    {
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: The flac file can need to be 16-bit PCM and mono. You can use http://www.audacityteam.org/ to check/convert your files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AsyncRecognize result is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906527/asyncrecognize-result-is-empty)