# google speech api Empty Results JSON

Tags: curl, google-api, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I made an API call normally with properly formatted JSON Request with mp3 file, and I am expecting the result JSON data to include "results" object with "alternatives" object with "transcript" and "confidence" values.

Instead what I get as a result is "{}" (an empty JSON object).

Operating system using is ubuntu15.04.

The JSON request file with the following text is created, and save it as a sync-request.json plain text file:

```
{
  "config": {
    "encoding": "LINEAR16",
    "sampleRate": 16000,
"languageCode": "en-US"
  },
  "audio": {
    "uri": "gs://audiobucketceino/Learn English - Lesson 41- Hi How are you - Pronunciation-[AudioTrimmer.com].mp3"
  }
}
```

curl used to make a speech:syncrecognize request is :

```
curl -s -k -H "Content-Type: application/json"     -H "Authorization: Bearer [access-token]"      https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:syncrecognize -d @sync-request.json
```

Test file is attached in :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7cqXnHXm78bLWdyYWhpVEdkT0U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Speech Recognition API Result is Empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906527/google-speech-recognition-api-result-is-empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The google speech API doesn't support mp3 files directly.  It only supports [the five listed in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/basics#audio-encodings).  The easiest thing would be to convert the mp3 file to a wav file using sox or a similar tool (`sudo apt-get install sox`):

```
sox lesson41.mp3 lesson41.wav
```

The wav file should be compatible with the `LINEAR16` encoding you supplied.  You'll want to make sure make sure the sample rate is 16k and the samples are 16 bit.  To be safe try this:

```
sox lesson41.mp3 -r 16000 -c 1 -b 16 lesson41.wav
```

If you have any trouble getting `sox` there are [lots of other tools that should be able to do the conversion too](http://stefaanlippens.net/audio_conversion_cheat_sheet/).