# Empty Response from Google Speech Api

Tags: java, httprequest, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

i searched for a long time on the web and didn't found anything helpful.

I record a 5s audiofile and upload it to Google Speech API. I get an empty response from Google, although in the same respond it says status=ok and give me the HTTP Responsecode 200. On the documentation it says that it was successful if it responses code 200
Here's my code for building the request

```
String audio = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString((WavFile.toString().getBytes()));

    JSONObject request_cfg = new JSONObject()
            .put("audio", new JSONObject()
                    .put("content", audio))
            .put("config", new JSONObject()
                    .put("encoding", "LINEAR16")
                    .put("sampleRate", 16000)
                    .put("languageCode", "de-DE"));
    String url = "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:syncrecognize?key=" + ___YOUR_API_KEY___;

    System.out.println(request_cfg);

    HttpResponse<JsonNode> request = Unirest.post(url)
            .body(request_cfg)
            .asJson();

    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(request);
    System.out.println(response);
```

with that code the request body looks like this:

`{"audio":"content":"QzpcVXNlcnNcQmVubmlcd29ya3NwYWNlXFBlcnNvbmFsX0FpX2RpZV96d2VpdGVccmVzXHJlY29yZGluZy53YXY"},"config":{"encoding":"LINEAR16","languageCode":"de-DE","sampleRate":16000}}`

and the full response looks like this:

`{"headers":{"X-Frame-Options":{"empty":false},"Transfer-Encoding":{"empty":false},"Server":{"empty":false},"Cache-Control":"empty":false},"Alt-Svc":{"empty":false},"X-Content-Type-Options":{"empty":false},"Vary":"empty":false},"X-XSS-Protection":"empty":false},"Date":{"empty":false},"Content-Type":"empty":false}},"rawBody":"java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@79ca92b9","statusText":"OK","body":{"array":{},"object":{}},"status":200}`

So I get the statusText=ok and an HTTP 200 Response, which according to the Google Docs means it was succsessful.

I recorded in Java. Here are the Parameters:

- sample rate is 16000, I tried 41000 but that didn't work eigher
- Bit/s 16
- Channels 1
- signed integer
- little endian

I don't know what I have to do to get an answer from Google

thanks in regard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Speech Recognition API Result is Empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906527/google-speech-recognition-api-result-is-empty)

Comment: I read it, but it seems that this is a different problem. I don't even get the name response he got.

Comment: i recorded the audio with java, too. So I set the parameters to exact the params google expects

Comment: Ok I tried a converted file and I got the same result

Comment: Your json is a bit mailformed, should be audio: {content:xxx}. It base64 string that short? It should be much longer. Maybe WavFile.toString() does not give you audio data but just a text name.

Comment: so with the content you were right. I now use the Files.readAllByte method and it gives me a String which is a lot longer.
But the response is still empty and has still the HttpResponse Code 200

Comment: with the json: [link](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/sync-recognize) google says it has to be the way I did it, doesn't it?

Comment: And why don't you use Google client library?

Comment: Because I don't understand it and this solution seemed much easier to me.