# Google Speech Recognition API Result is Empty (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-cloud-speech

**File Name:**- @"sound.caf"

**Request POST** = @"https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=mykey"

**Method :**   POST

**Content-Type :**  @"application/json"

**Body :**

```
audio = content =@"audi NSData" 
 config =     
        encoding = LINEAR16;
        languageCode = "en-US";
        maxAlternatives = 30;
        sampleRateHertz = 16000;
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906527/google-speech-recognition-api-result-is-empty

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that your audio file you provide to Google Speech is a file supported by the Google Speech API.

You should check that you are using a wav or flac file. 
and looking at your request you provide the api with a .caf file which is not supported.

Comment: Its support any one idea how to google json key use for ssl key,

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific with your question as its very unclear now what you are asking for.

Comment: Google cloud speech services generate json formate x.509 cert so that case how to share key with url.